# return mySQL query 'id' for an isset($_POST['$'])

Tags: php, mysql

The following code lists the `available matches` that users can accept and wager their coins against one another. At this moment in time, I can only list one match at a time.

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `create_id` ,`value`, `player1`, `match_id` FROM `multiplayer` WHERE `complete` = 0 ORDER BY `value` DESC LIMIT 1");
echo '<table>';
while($rowtwo = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $format_coins = number_format($rowtwo['value']);
    $value = $rowtwo['value'];
    $create_player = $rowtwo['player1'];
    $echo = $rowtwo['match_id'];
    $create_id = $rowtwo['create_id'];
    $button =   '
                <form action="multiplayer.php" method="POST">
                <input type="submit" name="'.$echo.'" value="Accept">
                </form>                 
                ';
    //$button = '<a href="match/'.$echo.'.php">Accept</a>';
    echo   '<tr>
            <td><font size="2" face="Lucida Sans Unicode"><strong>'.$rowtwo['player1'].'</strong> has wagered '.$format_coins.'M/Gp'.$button.'</td>
            </tr>';}
echo '</table>';
```

Now I need to change the `DESC LIMIT 1` to `DESC LIMIT 10` or so, but when I add more that one listing at a time, this following code cannot pick it up. It only picks up ONE of the listed.

```
    if (isset($_POST[''.$echo.''])) {
    if ($user_data['coins'] >= $value) {
        if ($user_data['user_id'] == $create_id) {
            echo 'You can\'t play yourself.';
        } else {
```

I need it so that it will be able to pick up the `match_id` from that button. If I set the button value to `$echo` it picks up the match ID, but it seems my problem lies with my `isset($_POST[''.$echo.''])` Can anyone help?

Comment: There is no more support for mysql_* functions, they are officially deprecated, no longer maintained and will be removed in the future. You should update your code with PDO or MySQLi to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: I don't understand the issue.  What is being posted?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but this is more of an educational process for myself. As I am a beginner. I don't plan on this script running long term.

Comment: Okay, the issue is. Where `DESC LIMIT 1` I want that to be 10, so it lists 10 of the available matches, with accept buttons next to them. When a user clicks accept, it will accept the match that the button is next to. It works with one, but not with more than 1.

Comment: Do you think adding my whole process after submitting into the while loop it will do it?

Comment: In what way does it not work? Error? Nothing happens? Wrong match selected?

Comment: It literally just does nothing, I set the if statement to return the $echo if the button was pressed. It will only return `one` of the listed items `match_id` - no errors, it seems that the $echo after coming out of the while loop returns only one value.

Comment: It would seem that I've fixed my issue, I just put my entire `if (isset($_POST))` into the while loop and it's picking up the different match_ids now. I'll answer my own question in 24 hours when I can.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding my

```
if (isset($_POST[''.$echo.''])) {
```

Into the while loops where the available `matches` are listed.